# What is a good guideline for creating challenging NPCs in Edge of the Empire?

Tags: npc, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

So while running an Edge of the Empire campaign, I am running into a problem of creating customized Nemesis and Rivals. I'm assuming that the former are basically player characters built with equal to greater xp, but is there an official formula for damage or toughness?

For instance, if a party primarily is combat light and is equipped with blaster pistols, what's a challenging set of stats as opposed to one built around big droids with bigger weapons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Threshold Formulae

There are no official formulae for **any** NPC's released to date.

That said, the *Gamemaster's Kit* explicitly points out that NPC Nemesis characters do not use the PC generation mechanics unless the GM wants to do so. Further, nemesis character experience is handled differently from PC's when buying talents - they don't need to do so in order, and they all cost the same.

Remember the axiomatic definitions:

- Minions have no stress, no skills, and take stress/stun as wounds. In groups, damage from one rolls on to the next in that group.
- Rivals have no stress threshold, and take stress/stun as wounds. They are individuals. They are out of action from any critical.
- Nemesis have a stress threshold.

In general, I have noted that:

- Minions have about 50% of what a similar PC would have for WT.
- Rivals often have about the same WT as starting PC's, tho' some have up to about 6 more. Rivals skills are typically no more than level 3, often only levels 1-2.
- Nemesis levels have *no less* than starting PC levels of WT and ST. Attributes often are well above 150 points; skills are often in excess of level 2.

## Encounter Balance

Balancing encounters is another matter entirely. There is no mechanical balancing included in any materials for *Edge of the Empire* nor for *Age of Rebellion* that I've seen.

Given the widely varied results of the dice rolling, mechanical balance is pretty hard to formulaically obtain.

Comment: After playing a few session I found this to be the case. Allowing Triumphs or an excess of advantages to end encounters or reach certain objectives quicker seems to be the best way to handle things. Let Criticals happen, make failure and success equally interesting, and use minions liberally.